# Import CSV into OrientDB with multiple edge properties

Tags: database, graph, orientdb

Given a CSV file like so:

vertex1,vertex2,edgeProperty1,edgeProperty2
(Two vertices and an edge between them with two properties)

What is the easiest way to import this into OrientDB?

A combination of Insert statements and SQLCreateEdge in a OrientDB console script perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer given by LVC @ https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/wjaotdHioVQ

```
create edge Likes from (create vertex People set name ="Alice") to (create vertex People set name ="Bob") set property1="something", property2= "somethingElse"
```

Or if there are vertices with multiple edges:

```
INSERT INTO People (name) values ("Alice")
INSERT INTO People (name) values ("Bob")

Create Edge Likes from (select from People where name ="Alice") to (select from People where name ="Bob") set property1="something", property2= "somethingElse"
```